# Cramer-Rao Bound for Time Delay given a Chirp Waveform with AWGN

Tags: radar, measurement, chirp, linear-chirp

In multiple sources (e.g. Richards, Mark A. "Fundamentals of Radar Signal Processing, Second Edition"), I come across the following expression for the CRLB for the time-delay parameter, assuming additive white Gaussian noise (assuming $s(t)$ is complex):
$$
\sigma^2_{t_0}\ge \frac{\sigma^2_n}{2} \left[ \sum_{n=0}^{N-1} \left| \frac{d s(t)}{dt} \right|^2 \right]^{-1}
$$
I can get this far if I assume the data contains only the signal plus AWGN, and I work through the derivation of the CRLB for a multivariate complex Gaussian distribution. So far, so good.

Now, I am trying to apply this to a chirp waveform. I am defining the chirp at baseband as
$$
u(t) =A \exp{\left[ j 2\pi \left( \frac{\alpha t^2}{2} + f_0 t\right) \right]}
$$
where $A$ is the amplitude, $\alpha$ is the chirp rate, and $f_0$ is the starting frequncy.

My next step is taking the derivative and finding the squared magnitude. Doing so gives me:
$$
\left| \frac{d s(t)}{dt} \right|^2 = 4A^2\pi^2 \left( \frac{d}{dt}  \left( \frac{\alpha t^2}{2} + f_0 t\right)\right)^2 
= 4A^2\pi^2 \left( \alpha t + f_0\right)^2
$$
From here, I would presumably plug this into the summation and expand/simplify. If I do that, I will end up with some expression that includes the chirp rate and the number of samples, and also the starting frequency $f_0$.

The question I have is - does this approach even make sense? I can wrap my head around the chirp rate and the number of samples increasing the Fisher information (and thus decreasing the CRLB), but I can't understand why $f_0$ would play a role at all.

I know there's another way to go about this exercise by converting the summation to an integral and forming an equivalence with the RMS bandwidth. However, if my approach above is correct, I expect to get something that doesn't disagree with the "standard" approach - hence the question.

Thanks!